# combination of group by and order by to get the results in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table that broadly having the details such as departmentid, location, DOJ,sal & age.

I wish to know the max sal, max age, depid & location group by depid :

I wrote the following query which is failed to execute on the table.

```
SELECT depid,location,MAX(sal),MAX(age) FROM company GROUP BY depid  ORDER BY doj DESC
```

Error:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Table data:
[image: table data]

result expected:
[image: out come]

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write like this:

```
SELECT 
depid,
first_value(location)over(partition by depid order by doj desc) location ,
MAX(sal),
MAX(age)
FROM company GROUP BY depid ORDER BY doj DESC
```

Comment: I want to get the top location id from all the depids as a result set.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways:

1. Include `location` to `GROUP BY` clause.
2. Use aggregate function like `MAX(location)` in your select.